# Webpack Vue project initializes using window.Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have a plugin for a website (WordPress) I built using webpack (loading esm build), for some reason instead of initializing using my webpack generated vue, it initializes using the full Vue build also loaded on the page (which i do not have control over).

Is there any way that I can prevent this from happening since I don’t have control over the site or what else is being loaded on the page?

I have webpack generating a vendors.js file that includes vue and vuex, but for some reason it always ends up using the full Vue build loaded on the page.

My guess is it's because the full build of Vue loads into the global namespace, so maybe webpack detects Vue already existing and uses that instead of my vendors webpacked file (which is loaded on the page)

Any suggestions, thoughts, or ideas on what I can do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you generate you dependencies into a `vendors.js` you do not take advantage of the module system. How is your plugin supposed to access Vue other than by deploying Vue globally?

Comment: @connexo through webpack chunking .. when i test this locally (without conflicting full vue build loaded), vue does not get exposed on global window object

Comment: *but for some reason it always ends up using the full Vue build loaded on the page* ...are you sure about that? Any error messages? This is hard to solve without additional information. What are the versions of the VUE (both). Share Webpack config. Any [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will be of great help (for example on Codesandbox)